React Native Expo background not covering iPhone notch
I am using React Native with Expo, and I am currently testing out gradients and trying to set the background color. I came across this bug where the notch of the device I am using (iPhone 13) is not being covered.
This is what the screen looks like. I want it so that the white parts are also colored in.
Here is my code:
const AppHome = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#9C51B6" }}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={["#9C51B6", "#5946B2"]}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>My App's Content</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
  );
};

// index.tsx
import { PaperProvider } from "react-native-paper";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import AppHome from "@/screens/AppHome/AppHome";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { LogBox } from "react-native";
import { MealContextProvider } from "@/hooks/useMealContext";
import FoodNutritionEditManual from "@/screens/FoodNutritionEditManual/FoodNutritionEditManual";
import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  User,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { FIREBASE_APP } from "@/FirebaseConfig";

const MealTrackingStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const AuthenticationStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();

const Home = () => {
  const auth = getAuth(FIREBASE_APP);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);
  console.log(user);

  return (
    <MealContextProvider>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
          <PaperProvider>
            {user ? (
              <MealTrackingStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Meal Home">
                // Screens
              </MealTrackingStack.Navigator>
            ) : (
              <AuthenticationStack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
              >
                <AuthenticationStack.Screen
                  name="Home Screen"
                  component={AppHome}
                />
              </AuthenticationStack.Navigator>
            )}
          </PaperProvider>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </MealContextProvider>
  );
};

export default Home;

I have tried this solution from github and removing the SafeAreaView, which is the current state of my code but it hasn't fixed anything, so I am unsure what could be causing it. If there are any possible work-arounds to this, let me know!
